# Wiring Diagram for Split Micro-USB Cable?

Tags: usb, cables, usb-device, computers, cable-assemblies

I have a customer who is looking for a split Micro-USB cable, which has one USB-A host connector on one end and two Micro-USB cables on the opposite end (they will be plugging into cameras). Can I simply wire it like this diagram I've attached? I believe he has software he is experimenting with where he is trying to control two cameras simultaneously. I've seen "zipper-stlye" split Micro cables like this. Is this simply the operative wiring? Thanks in advnace, friends.

[image]

Comment: Directly connecting two USB devices to one host port like this wouldn't work. A USB device needs to enumerate with the host. I don't know what the consequences of doing this are, but I'm pretty sure they aren't good. This is the reason USB hubs exist.

Comment: This will not work; we had basically the same question here a few days ago.  If you ignore the USB data aspect you might by some edge-case abuse of specs deliver power. But data is out of the question.  **USB requires a HUB for that**.

Comment: What happens when USB-A as a host attempts to program the local address in for micro-USB-a, and USB-b gets the same packet? You will have packet collisions and thus no connection to either micro-USB.

Answer (score 11):

This does not work. You will need a [USB hub.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub)

The USB Y cables you have seen use two [USB Type A male](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jNEF.jpg) plugs to one USB B type plug. Only the power lines are split to the extra plug.
This is not conform the USB specification. But it is a small hack to have more than the standard 2.5 Watts of power available, it is used for 2.5" hard disks that can't spin-up with just one plugs worth of power.

Comment: Could you hide a hub inside the A plug?

Comment: @Random832: There's no reason you couldn't CoB a die from, say, Genesys Logic in the connector.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah, I went looking for an example after I posted that comment.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen commercial cables like this out there, so they must be doing something like that with a CoB. If anybody has more info about that, or instructions on how to DIY it, I'd love to hear about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at these cables you mentioned - [This one, claiming to be the "original", is one example](http://www.angledcables.com/parts/rr-usb2-splitter.html), and their site does include a circuit diagram that makes it clear, you will see that either the type A connector is typically slightly larger than a normal one, or there is a small box in the middle of the cable. This is because USB hub electronics are hidden inside, rather than it being a simple plug connected directly to the wires. There's likely no particular advantage (other than space saving) over using a standard hub.